# correct typing in javascript when used in next js

Tags: javascript, typescript

what is the correct type to set `window.localStorage` in typescript?
I couldn't find information on the Internet

Comment: You can try `Storage`

Comment: gives an error message

Comment: because of this, I can not understand which type is more correct

Comment: _"gives an error message"_ What error message?

Comment: Possibly the object is null.

Comment: Initialize your object or set the type to `Storage | null`

Comment: everything also throws the previous error

Comment: That's a different problem and is not answerable without [mcve]. The correct type for a storage like local storage or session storage is `Storage`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `window.localStorage` is `Storage`.

It's described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)